# How do I target pre-Gingerbread devices in Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using the latest Android studio (2.3.3 at the time of writing), but I would like to target an older device which is still using Android Eclair (2.1).

When creating a new project 2.3 seems to be the lowest target-able SDK, even after downloading 2.1 via the SDK Manager. How would I go about developing for an older version?

[image: Android studio 2.3.3]

Edit: attempted to build API 9, and change the manifest to 7, but I the following error occurs on build:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 7 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.0.0-alpha1] C:\Users\BPC\.android\build-cache\3e76789f4fbefa52f0a9111623ac319d35790f7f\output\AndroidManifest.xml
Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.coreui" to force usage
```

Comment: Could you just choose API 9 in the new project wizard, then in the manifest file change the target API to something lower?

Comment: You may try to create new project using API9 and then manually change it in build.gradle file.

Comment: I was wondering about that. I'll give it a try  and revert back

Comment: @Brian No such luck: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 7 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library

Comment: Don't use `android-support:26` if you want to target such devices

Comment: Hmm, are you able to change this "version 14" that the error is giving you?

Comment: I attempted to, but changing the version caused a cascade of other changes in other files, and it ultimately never worked.

Answer (score 0):

Is there functionality that is not working in the older version.  I.E. did you try it on an older version and it dies at a certain point?  You should be able to go back to API 1 but Google Play store and Firebird will only allow you API 14.

If there is one or two pieces of code that isn't working, you should be able to determine a code level to execute:

```
if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >=   Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop) 
{
    // Do things the Lollipop way
}
else
{
    // Do things the pre-Lollipop way
}
```

Target Framework is set to Android 5.0 (API Level 21) and its Minimum Android version is set to Android 4.1 (API Level 16).